Lists Workarounds for Geometry Nodes
I am aware that lists are in development. However, are there any current workarounds to simply compare a custom list of non-sequential integers? ("Array of integers" in programming speak.)
Perhaps if you "imported" named attributes (a list) from another object, but is that possible?


Are you trying "id in list" or are you trying "id[i] == list[i]"? (Does "list" have the same length as "points")

Some ideas here: Geometry Nodes - Extrude edge by ID

Create any geometry with the number of vertices equal to the array length.
(A plane, for instance, get one edge and subdivide it)
Then create a script to set the array values to each point:
import bpy

#getting an object that has 5 vertices - used subdivide on an edge of a plane
mesh = bpy.data.objects["Plane.001"].data

#create attribute
attribute = mesh.attributes.new(name="new attribute", type="INT", domain="POINT")

#your array
attribute_values = [200, 300, 400, 500, 600] #5 values, for 5 vertices

#set the attribute
attribute.data.foreach_set("value", attribute_values)

Then with these nodes, you can make a comparison "one by one" (provided your geometry has the same number of points as the "list" geometry)

A little explanation:

The "sample index" node creates a context based on the "list" geometry, this context is separated from your geometry. It can be evaluated isolatedly.
The rest of the nodes are evaluated on the context of "your" geometry
The comparison is only possible because both arrays have the same number of elements (they're compared one by one)
For different solutions, you could explore a "repeat zone" node to make iterations


Ah this! The sample index i didn’t think of to create a different context. Thank you!
